# VBA Clear and Copy without blank rows to another sheet on entering value greater than

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

My 2010 macro updates on opening a sheet. Does 2016 work the same when when they have the target sheet opened in a new 'instance'? It has to be idiot proof (I don't know why they asked me to do it :P). So the macro has to run once when opening the sheet; if the sheet is opened on the second monitor run every time a value is inserted over 119 in the source sheet; Don't run unnecessary because of the potentially very large sheets and meh laptops.

I've made this macro so the sheets my colleges are using don't need 'complex' formulas or macros to clear blank rows before it's exported to Word. I've made it in 2010, but I can't test it on 2016 til next week.

The macro that on the target sheet (J03);

```
Private Sub worksheet_activate()
```

And on the source sheet (WTB);

```
 Private Sub Run_When_Value_Greather_Than_119_Is_Entered_In_Column_G()
```

Google is clogged with answers and results about blank rows, copying, blank rows, running on other activation ways and non blank rows. I probably don't know what to look for either.

The full code;

```
Private Sub worksheet_activate()
  Dim Max As Long, MaxD As Long       'Determine the amount of filled rows
  Dim wsWtB As Worksheet, wsJ03 As Worksheet
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer      'i and j for the row numbers

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'screenupdating of for max speeds

  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Set wsJ03 = Sheets("J_03")
  Set wsWtB = Sheets("WTB")

  Max = WorksheetFunction.Max(wsWtB.Range("A3:A1600"))  'Amount of rows with data
  Max = Max + 3                                         'Ignore the headers
  MaxD = WorksheetFunction.Max(wsJ03.Range("A3:A1600"))
  MaxD = MaxD + 2
  j = 9                   'The rownumber where the copying needs to start
    wsJ03.Range("B9", Cells(MaxD, 5)).ClearContents  'Clear the old values
      For i = 3 To Max    'The copying loop has to start after the headers at row 3
        If wsWtB.Cells(i, 7).Value > 119 Then   'Do stuff if...
          wsJ03.Cells(j, "B").Value = Chr(39) & wsWtB.Cells(i, "B").Value 'At a  '
          wsJ03.Cells(j, "C").Value = Chr(39) & wsWtB.Cells(i, "C").Value 'at the start
          wsJ03.Cells(j, "D").Value = Chr(39) & wsWtB.Cells(i, "D").Value 'so a zero is
          wsJ03.Cells(j, "E").Value = Chr(39) & wsWtB.Cells(i, "E").Value 'displayed
          j = j + 1       'Set the next row for the target sheet
        Else
      End If
    Next i
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It's the first piece of code that I got working without hiccups :-) Feel free to comment and ad the propper tags.

Koen.

Edit; (Alternative ways to look for the last cell)

```
?thisworkbook.sheets("WTB").cells(rows.Count,"A").end(xlup).row
  1047 '<- Rownumber of the last cell with a Formula to create/force 
        successive 
        numbers
?thisworkbook.sheets("WTB").columns("A").Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, 
 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
  5    '<- Rownumber of the last cell with a value. Includes the header 
        rows
?WorksheetFunction.Max(thisworkbook.sheets("WTB").Range("A3:A1600"))
  3    '<- Highest number in A3:A1600 and also the amount units/rows that 
        need to be copied to "J_03"
```

I needed a function that gave me the amount of 'things' on the sheet. In this case it's 3, but it could go up to 1600.

Edit 2; (google sheet so you can see what i'm working on)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I5qLeOS0DWcwncs_ium_J0Vp6b4nzTsiE0ndbKtpsC0/edit?usp=sharing

Edit 3; there was an error in the clear range part.
 wsJ03.Range("B9", **Cells(MaxD, 5))**.ClearContents  'Clear the old values

Comment: Well this looks like it should work,... If you come across any specific issues then let us know... I would change the way you calculate your Max to something like Max = wsWtB.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Hey, the End(xlup) also find the cells with formulas. I opted using range.find(find "*" & xlvalues) but the users are forced to use successive numbers in this sheet (there is a lot of COUNTA() and MAX(A) to make sure they do. Its making the code run whenever someone enters 120 or more in column G that's giving me a headache. EDIT; there was actually a random formula at the last row :P

Comment: To late to edit; I've added the other options to find the last row and why they didn't work. Maybe someone stumbles upon them and finds it useful.      I'm going to try it with;  "ws_change() & Intersect(Target, Range())" found on Extended office; https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4423-excel-run-macro-on-cell-change.html .  Was thinking to complicated i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like the following, but make sure you place the code in the Sheet where the values might be changing (Sheets("WTB")):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 7 Then 'If something changed in column G
        If Target.Value > 119 Then 'and if the value is higher than 119
        NextFreeRow = Sheets("J_03").Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'Or Do your copying stuff, you can use Target.column or Target.row to find the address of the cell that got a value higher than 119
            Sheets("J_03").Cells(NextFreeRow, "B").Value = Chr(39) & Sheets("WTB").Cells(Target.Row, "B").Value 'At a  '
            Sheets("J_03").Cells(NextFreeRow, "C").Value = Chr(39) & Sheets("WTB").Cells(Target.Row, "C").Value 'at the start
            Sheets("J_03").Cells(NextFreeRow, "D").Value = Chr(39) & Sheets("WTB").Cells(Target.Row, "D").Value 'so a zero is
            Sheets("J_03").Cells(NextFreeRow, "E").Value = Chr(39) & Sheets("WTB").Cells(Target.Row, "E").Value 'displayed
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I could give the first cell in the column a defined name or even the entire range could be named. But there's code that checks all named ranges and determines if it need to be copied to Word. So i try and use as little as possible. When they change the headers they are going to run into trouble indeed. I'm adding Find.range() to find the last row and then count backwards from there; Last row - max = first cell after header. I've made a Google sheets to make it more visual; https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I5qLeOS0DWcwncs_ium_J0Vp6b4nzTsiE0ndbKtpsC0/edit?usp=sharing @Xabier rying now :).

Comment: @koenvantiel please have a look at my updated answer, I think it will do as you expect.

Comment: @ Xabier It neatly adds the data at the next empty row, which is 1601 :P I can get this working. I'm going to use the max value or range.find() instead of NextFreeRow if i can't find a way to have it only look at column B to E. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @koenvantiel please could you mark my response as an answer if it has helped you? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

2 months later, thought i'd show my final work;

The Union() functions lets you (or me in this case), improve the speed of the sheets:

```
For i = 1 to LastRow
  If Ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value > 119 Then
    Union(Ws2.Cells(i, 4), Ws2.Cells(i, 5), Ws2.Cells(i, 6)).Value = 
    Union(Ws1.Cells(y, 1), Ws1.Cells(y, 2), Ws1.Cells(y, 3)).Value: y = y + 1
  end if
Next
```

It's about 30% faster then using    cel1, 2, 3.value = cel5, 6, 7.value    when it's simply copying all rows without the If.

When my workbook needs to fill 50 sheets like this and has 25 rows of data it took 4,5 seconds on average, with the Union() it's 1,6.  When there are 1000 rows its goes from ~23 to 9 seconds but the variations is very high. Depending on the If's;

For some sheets it's not "If > 119 then";

```
If cellAL.Value = "x" Then     'if the cell exactly "x" Then do stuf
If Not cellAL.Value <> vbNullString Then   'if the cell = NotEmpty 
                                            vbNullString 
                  is faster then "" because it's actually less ones and zeros
If InStr(cellAll, "x") Then     'looks for all x's in the cell.
```

To find the last row without beein affected by format, formulas and other stuff;

```
myLastRow = .Columns("A").Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

"*" 'is something like "any/all characters". A Space or Alt + Enter can make 
                                             a big mess
```

try the direct window to see what it does:

```
?activesheet.Columns("A").Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, _ 
                               SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Ps for my CanaDerp buddy; Hope you can get it working with this!